# Prove that $|-x| = |x|$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, absolute-value

Using only the definition of Absolute Value:

$\left|x\right| =  \begin{cases} x & x> 0 \\
-x & x < 0 \\
0 & x = 0,\end{cases}$

Prove that $|-x| = |x|.$

This seems so simple, but I keep getting hung up. I use the definition insert $-x$ into the definition, but I end up with:

$\left|-x\right| =  \begin{cases} -x & x> 0 \\
-(-x) & x < 0 \\
0 & x = 0\end{cases}$

which doesn't make sense to me. It certainly doesn't equal $|x|,$ does it?

I would use $|x| = \sqrt{x^2}$ but I am supposed to prove that identity later in the problem set. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You multiplied $x$ by $-1$ in your second piecewise function, but you forgot to do so for the inequalities $x>0$ and $x<0$.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

$\left|-x\right| =  \begin{cases} -x & \bbox[5px,border:2px solid #F0A]{-x> 0} \\
-(-x) & \bbox[5px,border:2px solid #F0A]{-x < 0} \\
0 & \bbox[5px,border:2px solid #F0A]{-x = 0}\end{cases}$

Answer (score 4):

Rather, you should have $$\lvert-x\rvert=\begin{cases}-x & -x>0\\-(-x) & -x<0\\0 & -x=0.\end{cases}$$ Can you take it from there?

Comment: I totally understand where I was going wrong, and I now completely understand the problem and solution.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an even quicker way.  Use the property $|ab|=|a||b|$ on $|-x|$.

Comment: Have these properties been proven yet though? Otherwise, how do you know this property is true?

Comment: Good point, but I still think the idea is worth mentioning.

Comment: Actually, one of the next problems was to prove this identity.

Answer (score 2):

Good question! You need to flip the $>$ and $<$ signs in the definition.

It's for the same reason that you need to flip the sign when you multiply both sides of $a > b$ by $-1$, getting $-a < -b$.

Answer (score 1):

Proof by cases:

$1)$ $x \gt 0$, and so $-x \lt 0$

$|x|=x, |-x|=-(-x)=x$

$2)$$x=0$ (clear)

$3)$ $x \lt 0$, and so $-x \gt 0$

then $|x|=-(x)$

$|-x|=-(x)$

QED

Answer (score 0):

Your substitutions show that $|-x|=-|x|$. which is false.
The error comes from the fact that when introducing 
the minus sign you did not swap the sense of inequalities

once swapped

$|-x|= -x\quad  (x<0)$

$|-x| = x\quad  (x>0)$

$|-x| = 0\quad  (x=0)$

you see that $|-x|$ definition matches that of $|x|$ again.

Comment: Can you show us, besides $x=0$, where your first line is true? Also, the OP knows what you've answered with- what he doesn't understand is why the domains didn't match up (i.e., why his final result didn't resemble the original statement, if $|x|=|-x|$).

Comment: The error comes from the fact that it does not switch the signs of domains. The expression of |-x| is false.

Comment: Your edited answer is clearer; cool.

Answer (score 0):

You can just do case analysis. Check the cases of when $x>0$, $x=0$ and $x<0$